# unable to access /admin/ in Django app

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm trying to go through this tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/ for django and I can make it to the beginning of Part 2 and after following it step by step, when I go to the /admin/ site it produces the exact same output as the normal localhost:8000 site. Any idea why that might happen?  Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: My urls.py file is completely commented out.  Upon uncommenting the section labelled for enabling the admin page, rerunning the django server, and opening the /admin/ page in my browser I get the following error:

```
NameError at /admin/

name 'admin' is not defined

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version:     1.5.1
Exception Type:     NameError
Exception Value:    

name 'admin' is not defined

Exception Location:     /home/<username>/Django Test/mysite/mysite/urls.py in <module>, line 16
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.4
Python Path:    

['/home/jgreen/Django Test/mysite',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
```

Server time:    Tue, 11 Jun 2013 16:47:13 -0500

Comment: Check your django version and the tutorial version you are reading(dev). Make sure they are the same.

Comment: What's your urls.py file look like?

Comment: They are both for the most recent version.

Comment: @avorum Have a look to the [1.5 version tutorial] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/), they show how to activate the admin site. This may be your problem.

Comment: @Ander2 that's the part I was working through when I got to this problem

Comment: @avorum Check that my link is for 1.5 version and the one you posted in the question is for dev version. They are similar, but not the same.

Comment: Ah, that did the trick, much obliged for the assistance.

Comment: @avorum I always found handy to replace `/dev/` with `/1.x/` in the official documentation urls.

Comment: can you show your urls.py ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons of this exception. This in my example of urls.py. Most likely that you forgot to add the admin URL at urls.py.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

You need to add the Admin URL first to make the admin work. :D.

Answer (score 0):

please import admin to urls.py file `from django.contrib import admin` then it will work